# JFreechart in Netbeans 8.0.2 & JDK 1.8.0 NOT Working

Tags: java, netbeans, jfreechart

Anybody who knows why `JFreechart` is not working in my NetBeans version 8.0.2 and my JDK version 1.8.0. When I run the program, nothing displays?

How can I show a bar graph in my system when `JFreechart` is not working in my system?

Anybody who knows how to solve my `JFreechart` problem?

My Imports are:

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
```

Heres my Code:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset barchartdata = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
barchartdata.setValue(100000,"","Name");
barchartdata.setValue(200000,"","Name");
barchartdata.setValue(500000,"","Name");    
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createAreaChart("Instructor Name","","", barchartdata, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);
CategoryPlot barchrt = barChart.getCategoryPlot();
barchrt.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.ORANGE); 
ChartPanel barPanel = new ChartPanel(barChart);
jPanel11.removeAll();
jPanel11.add(barPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);            
jPanel11.validate();
```

I'm using JfreeChart 1.0.19.

Comment: Can you post a runnable example? Was it working on a previous version of Java and/or Netbeans?

Comment: It doesn't show up when I run the project >_<

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 1):

I ran this which just put your panel into a JFrame and showed it on the EventQueue  and it seemed to work in Netbeans 8.0.2 and JDK 1.8.0_60.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
    DefaultCategoryDataset barchartdata = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    barchartdata.setValue(100000, "", "Name");
    barchartdata.setValue(200000, "", "Name");
    barchartdata.setValue(500000, "", "Name");
    JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createAreaChart("Instructor Name", "", "", barchartdata, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);
    CategoryPlot barchrt = barChart.getCategoryPlot();
    barchrt.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.ORANGE);
    ChartPanel barPanel = new ChartPanel(barChart);
    JPanel jPanel11 = new JPanel();
    jPanel11.removeAll();
    jPanel11.add(barPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jPanel11.validate();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(jPanel11);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
});
```

Produced this:

[image: Screenshot of triangular graph]

Also I should perhaps mention that I created a new maven project and added this as a dependancy.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Works for me, too; see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).